# Why is my canvas image not showing using Tkinter and Pillow?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to show an image on a canvas and I have something like this

```
background = tkinter.Canvas(window, width=t, height=t, background="#000", bd=0, highlightthickness=0)

background.pack()
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("img.png"))


class x:
    def __init(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.image = img
        self.sprite = background.create_image(self.x, self.y, image=self.image)
```

I'm not expert in Tkinter but from my memory I should just be able to create an image like this so my object x has a sprite that I can move when his coords move (the function works).

Do you have any idea why the image doesn't show? By the way, the code works, and I can use correctly background.coords after that (or at least it doesn't throw errors).

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps the `x` and `y` values are bogus. Hard to say without a [mre]…

Comment: Nothing is calling your `__init` function. Did you intend to type `__init__`?

Comment: yes, I found the fix which is related to macOS and pillow compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the issue was because PNG are not read correctly with Pillow on macOS apparently. I converted to jpg and it works nice.